# Nesting arrays do behave as expected in javascript

Tags: javascript

In python the following code:

```
>>> x=[]
>>> y=[[1],[2]]
>>> y
[[1], [2]]
>>> x.append(y)
>>> x
[[[1], [2]]]
```

Works as expected creating a nesting array of arrays.

In am expecting the following javascript code to do the same:

```
x=[]
y=[[1],[2]]
x.push(y);
```

But no. This spinet results to the following as the value of x:

```
[[1, 2]]
```

instead of the desired:

```
[[ [1], [2] ]]
```

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not seeing that behavior for the [push() method](http://www.javascripture.com/Array#push).  I ran the following:

```
var x=[];
var y=[[1],[2]];
x.push(y);
console.dir(x);
```

And got:

```
[ [ [ 1 ], [ 2 ] ] ]
```

Which matches your expected value.

Comment: I can verify what you say here. Apparently it has to do with the javascript interpreter I am using and the way the array is displayed.

Comment: @JohnP What interpreter are you using?